# DirectoryPartitioning in pyarrow (python)

Tags: pyarrow

```
dataset = ds.dataset("abfs://test", format="parquet", partitioning="hive", filesystem=fs)
```

I can read datasets with the pyarrow dataset feature, but how can I write to a dataset with a different schema?

I seem to be able to import DirectoryPartitioning, for example, but I cannot figure out a way to save the data to create a schema like this:

```
from pyarrow.dataset import DirectoryPartitioning


partitioning = DirectoryPartitioning(pa.schema([("year", pa.int16()), ("month", pa.int8()), ("day", pa.int8())]))
print(partitioning.parse("/2009/11/3"))
```

Will we continue to use `write_to_dataset` to write Parquet files, or will there be a new method specific to the datasets class?

Comment: With pyarrow 1.0, only reading is supported. In the next release, also writing will be supported, though. An open PR adding the functionality: https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/7921/

Comment: Got it. I thought I was doing something incorrectly.